# How to remove left recursion from A -> Aα | ε

Tags: recursion, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, left-recursion, context-free-language

I think the left-recursion for this grammar is not removable. Correct me if I am wrong.
α is Alpha that is a Non-terminal
ε is Epsilon.

Comment: Not sure if this is off-topic for this site or not, but you can just swap `A -> αA | ε`. Both rule definitions will be equivalent to the regular expresion `α*`, that is, a sequence of as many alpha characters you wish (including none).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left recursion can be removed from the grammar; Here is the grammar without left recursion:

```
A -> A' | ε
A' -> α A
```

You could also do how @Mephy did with right recursion:

```
A -> α A | ε
```

Note that (as @Mephy said) this grammar is just zero or more `α`s (`α*`).